# Is there a way to run a view inside a partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I know this is odd. but I can't figure other ways to do what I need.
I have a controller: report and a view: report.
Also I have a view that acts as a dashboard where I can see several zones (partials).
I need to add this report view to my dashboard but don't know how.
This report view utilizes complex logic from controller and displays the results.
How could I "stuck" the (logic+presentation) of exising view (report) into my partial, so I could use it on my dashboard??

Thank you.
Valve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I hope I'm understanding the problem, here...)

This part seemed significant:

> This report view utilizes complex
>   logic from controller

As a general rule, controllers should be simple. Really simple. The rule of thumb is "thin controller, fat model" (Rails Envy made some entertaining but useful [screencasts on the subject](http://www.railsenvy.com/2008/6/3/mvc-videos))

What would happen if you created a new model (quite possibly not inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base) that encapsulated the logic you want to deliver into the partial? Then different controller/action combinations can deliver the information into your views as necessary/required.

Or have I completely missed the point (not impossible!)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago, when they deprecated render_controller. The only solution I found then was to use ajax, passing a parameter to the page you want to load that bypasses the layout.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken you can do a render_component, but this is completely frowned upon nowadays.

This is the easiest way to your problem though

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to refactor the code from the report controller (if this is the one that contains the "complex" logic) and put it into a wrapper class that can be used by the dashboard and report view.